# Xcode7 Core Plot Errors: CPTPlot, NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, xcode7, core-plot

I'm new to both Xcode7 and Core Plot, and I'm trying to follow this beginner tutorial here:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1

Everything seems fine until I have to add this code into CPDPieChartViewController.m

```
#pragma mark - CPTPlotDataSource methods
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot {
    return 0;
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    return 0;
}

-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    return nil;
}

-(NSString *)legendTitleForPieChart:(CPTPieChart *)pieChart recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    return @"";
}

#pragma mark - UIActionSheetDelegate methods
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
}
```

I get a number of errors after this: 
in CPDPieChartViewController.m: (CPTPlot *) Expected a type, 
in CPDConstants.h: unknown type name NSString (I have ensured there are no .c files in my xcode project. Are there other reasons for this to appear?)

I have also made a screen shot of the errors on each file
[image: CPDConstants.h]

[image: CPDPieChartViewController.m]

Has anyone dealt with this before. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: did you remember to add the 3 .h files to the project pre-compiled header?

Comment: Missing an import of Foundation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some import statements in the header files. Since `CPDConstants.h` only references `NSString`, it needs Foundation at a minimum (`#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`).

`CPDPieChartViewController.h` and any other file that references Core Plot types needs to import the Core Plot header. Use `#import <CorePlot/CorePlot.h>` if you included Core Plot as a framework or `#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"` if you're using the static library.